# How to simulate in Gazebo Moveit2 planning executing

Tags: gazebo, moveit

I'm using ROS2-humble with MoveIt2. I created a MoveIt package, and I'm able to run demo.launch.py. Everything looks like it works there.

I'd now like to be able to run my arm in a Gazebo environment, and see the plans move in the Gazebo simulation. How should this be done?

Answer (score 0):

This would involve editing your launch file to spawn the entity in Gazebo. There are multiple ways of doing this, but the simplest is to use the `robot_description` topic to spawn an entity in Gazebo. This can be done as follows:

```
spawnEntity = Node(
    package='gazebo_ros',
    executable='spawn_entity.py',
    arguments=['-topic', 'robot_description', '-entity', 'my_robot'],
    output='screen',
    emulate_tty=True,
)
```

Generally, this should do it, but you might need to install some packages such as `gazebo_ros2_control` and a variety of others.

There are a few resources which might be able to help you better:

1. [Articubot One launch_sim](https://github.com/joshnewans/articubot_one/blob/humble/launch/launch_sim.launch.py) : This example here shows how to launch a simulation for a mobile robot in Gazebo.
2. [ROS 2 for Doosan Robots](https://github.com/doosan-robotics/doosan-robot2) : This might be a little dated, but since you are using MoveIt2, you will find a good example of how to set up and work with a robot arm in this repository.