# How to combine Moveit2 and Gazebo in Ros-Humble

Tags: gazebo, moveit, ros-humble, spawn-model, moveit2

anyone has an example on how to combine Moveit2 and Gazebo and to make  the robot move in Gazebo using the Rviz2 from Moveit2

Comment: Try to follow this answer:
https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/104062/how-to-simulate-in-gazebo-moveit2-planning-executing

Comment: @JakubIvan thanks. I will look into it